# Datanucleus RDBMS JPA Entitymanager GAE Criteriabuilder Multiple Joins Error org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.QueryToSQLMapper

Tags: java, mysql, google-app-engine, jpa, datanucleus

I'm getting this Error

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.QueryToSQLMapper.compileFromClassExpression(QueryToSQLMapper.java:1199)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.QueryToSQLMapper.compileFrom(QueryToSQLMapper.java:436)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.QueryToSQLMapper.compile(QueryToSQLMapper.java:380)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.JPQLQuery.compileQueryFull(JPQLQuery.java:799)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.JPQLQuery.compileInternal(JPQLQuery.java:280)
>     at org.datanucleus.store.query.Query.executeQuery(Query.java:1747)
>     at org.datanucleus.store.query.Query.executeWithMap(Query.java:1693)
>     at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAQuery.getResultList(JPAQuery.java:185)
>     at ...........

I try to execute

```
      EntityManager mgr = null;
      Cursor cursor = null;
      List<StudentMark> execute = null;

    try {

        mgr = getEntityManager();
        CriteriaBuilder cb = mgr.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<StudentMark> query = cb
                .createQuery(StudentMark.class);
        Root<StudentMark> from = query.from(StudentMark.class);
        CriteriaQuery<StudentMark> select = query.select(from);

        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

        /* Set of Filters Use to Filter Query Results */
        if (subjectId != null) {
            predicates.add(cb.equal(from.join("subject").get("subjectId"),
                    cb.parameter(Long.class, "subjectId")));
        }

        if (studentRecordId != null) {
            predicates.add(cb.equal(from.join("studentRecord").get("studentRecordId"),
                    cb.parameter(Long.class, "studentRecordId")));

        }


        query.select(from).where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[] {}));

        TypedQuery<StudentMark> typedQuery = mgr.createQuery(select);

        /* set the parameters of the above mentioned filters */
        if (subjectId != null) {
            typedQuery.setParameter("subjectId", subjectId);
        }
        if (studentRecordId != null) {
            typedQuery.setParameter("studentRecordId", studentRecordId);
        }

        if (limit != null) {
            typedQuery.setFirstResult(0);
            typedQuery.setMaxResults(limit);
        }

        execute = (List<StudentMark>) typedQuery.getResultList();
    } finally {
        mgr.close();
    }
```

Error creating when i try to pass 2 parameters in same time to query. If i pass only one parameter the result generate generate fine.

I'm using these jars [image: Jars]
And use google app engine standard project with cloud sql
here is my persistance.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">


 <persistence-unit name="Demo">
  <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
      <!-- this is required if you're connecting to a 2nd generation cloud-sql db -->
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="zaq123!@#" />
      <property name="datanucleus.autoCreateSchema" value="true"/>
  </properties>
 </persistence-unit>
```

Comment: If you are using DataNucleus with RDBMS then why would you even think of using v3.x when it is not supported and hasn't been for years???? Current version is 5.1.x (or even 5.2.x). And if using RDBMS then "datanucleus-appengine" (some Google code for storing data in their "Appengine/Datastore" DB) is not being used, so why do you have that in your classpath???

Comment: Have you tried with a current version of DataNucleus yet?